# Sort list of lists of strings in Python

Tags: python, list, lambda

How can I sort the following based on the 1st element?

```
list1 = [["Value313",1],["Value421",3],["Value234",2]]
```

Ultimately, I should get the following:

```
list1 = [["Value234",2],["Value313",1],["Value421",3]]
```

Comment: `list1.sort()` will sort list1 (in place) on the first element as a default

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default sort order of lists (*lexicographically*) is already how you want it.

```
>>> list1 = [["Value313",1],["Value421",3],["Value234",2]]
>>> list1.sort()
>>> print list1
[['Value234', 2], ['Value313', 1], ['Value421', 3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sorted(list1,key=lambda x : x[0])

[['Value234', 2], ['Value313', 1], ['Value421', 3]]
```

Use sorted and use a key `lambda x[0]` where `x[0]` is the first element in each sublist

Or sort in place to avoid creating a new list:

```
list1 = [["Value313",1],["Value421",3],["Value234",2]]

list.sort(list1,key=lambda x : x[0])
print list1
[['Value234', 2], ['Value313', 1], ['Value421', 3]]
```

Comment: what exactly was the downvote for?

Answer (score 4):

To sort `list1` in place (without creating another list) use:

```
from operator import itemgetter
list1.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
```

If you want to create another list and leave `list1` unsorted use:

```
from operator import itemgetter
list2 = sorted(list1, key=itemgetter(0))
```

You could use a lambda, but [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) normally has better performance since it's at C level.

Comment: Sure I did, for for a list of pair of integers and using `sorted`, the `itemgetter` solution on my (old) machine does *207 µs per loop*, the `lambda` *359 µs per loop*